# Symfony 3 : How to access my database inside my provider? (with doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I would like to access my database that contains all my user inside my provider with doctrine. I followed a tutorial (http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html) to build my provider for my user, so I have an loadUserByUsername function :

```js
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        // make a call to your webservice here
        $player = new Player();
        $player = $this->getDoctrine()
                         ->getRepository('AppBundle:Player')
                         ->findOneByPseudo($username);
        // pretend it returns an array on success, false if there is no user

        if ($player) {
            
            return $player;
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }
```

But of course my getDoctrine() function is undefined. So there is something I don't understand with the provider, I am trying to use it to be authenticated when I login so I need a provider, but why I can't search inside my database? How should I write this function? Thank for your help

EDIT : 
When I add doctrine by service.yml (and after writting my constructor inside my provider), I have this error :

```
FatalThrowableError in PlayerProvider.php line 13:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Security\PlayerProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in /home/jean/PW6/SkA/SkeletonsOnlineV2/skeleton-online/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 327
```

EDIT 2 : When I just put arguments: ['@doctrine'] inside my service.yml, I get an error that says that doctrine is undefined

EDIT 3 : It works now, I just made a dumb mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read further, it says the following (emphasis mine):

> The real implementation of the user provider **will** probably **have some dependencies** or configuration options or other services. **Add these as arguments in the service definition**.

So in your case it would be something like

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.webservice_user_provider:
        class: AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUserProvider
        arguments: ['@doctrine']
```

And your class needs a constructor

```
class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct (\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then in your method replace `$this->getDoctrine()` with just `$this->doctine`

Comment: In a standard installation of Symfony, the servicename of the entity-manager is ``'@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'``, not just ``'@doctrine'``

Comment: @MichaelHirschler The question was asking about the registry, not entity manager. Check what getDoctrine() in controller does